# No Gamepad Detected using SNES USB

Tags: retropie, gamepad

I'm using a USB SNES Controller adapter I made using a PIC32MX as a USB HID Gamepad. I've been using it with Windows machines for a while without any issues. It seems to work everywhere except in ES/RetroPie so far.

When I start RetroPie on my Pi 3, EmulationStation says no gamepad is detected and I can't configure inputs.

The device is listed under `/etc/input/js0` and the buttons all work when I run `jstest`, but I can not get it to be recognized by EmulationStation.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you are the same guy that asked about this issue at the RetroPie forums, but compiling all the knowledge from the thread there, basically you will have to:

1 - Access your Retropie through ssh, and use the default credentials(host:`retropie`, user: `root`, pass: `raspberry`)

2 - Dump your device info with `udevadm` and `dmesg`

`udevadm info /dev/input/js0`

`dmesg | grep -i joystick`

3 - Create the `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-gamepad.rules` file, with your `DEVICE_NAME` obtained from `dmesg`(name inside brackets) and `ID_INPUT` from `udevadm`:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="input", ATTRS{name}=="NAME OF DEVICE", MODE="0666", ENV{ID_INPUT_JOYSTICK}="1"
```

**References:**

- [USB Nes Controller - Gamepad not detected](https://retropie.org.uk/forum/topic/8723/gamepad-not-detected)